# Read unknown structure data by Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, readfile, cell-array

I want to read a ptx file which contains 2 head lines and matrix information. The structure of the matrix part is unknown. it could be 4, 6 or 7 columns. I want to real the data at without check the data structure first.

I curretly using the following code

```
fID=fopen(filename,'r')
C = textscan(fID,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f','HeaderLines',2)
M = [C{:}]
```

I have to check the data and count the column number first. Here I use 7 "%f" to deal with 7-olumn data. I cannot process large data set with different column number. Can someone please help me to create a code automatically scape the headlines and read n-column data into floating format cell array.

Thanks

Comment: Does a file have variable number of columns from row to row or is the number of columns just unknown on a per-file basis?

Comment: Please demonstrate the problem.  Also, don't forget to `fclose(fID)`!

Comment: @chappjc No, each row has the same number of columns. Only each file may have different columns. For example. a file has n rows 7 column and others may have m rows 6 columns (on all rows). How many columns of a file is unknown (columns unknown on a per-file basis).

Comment: So you are saying that you have many files. The number of columns can vary between the files but not within the file itself?

Comment: Matlab have a lot of support for reading files. If your file is written according to some standard format (which it should be) it is likely that there is a file that does what you want eg, `csvread`, `xlsread`, `xmlread`,`importdata`,... In other case, if you may have to know the structure data I fear, or at least scan the header, first line or so.

Comment: @kkuilla Yes kkuilla you are right.

Comment: @patrik The data is called ptx file. I haven't found any function in Matlab can automatically read it.

Comment: @user3004698 Ok I see. The best I can come up with then is to check the first row and then assume that format. An alternative to this can be if you know the number of columns beforehand an add this as an extra argument. Also, if the file have any similarities to another file type, you could probably use the same function. Further, matlab does not "automatically" do anything. There are instructions for everything.